# How to add prefix to every copter in Erle-brain using Mavros

Tags: mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, i have bought Erle-brain v3 that included ROS kinetic. Erle-brain automatically runs roscore. And i don't understand how to rename topics (or add prefix). It needed for dividing topics`information from each other. I mean, we have for example list of topics:

```
/mavros/global_position/global

/mavros/imu/data
```

etc.

And i want to get:

```
/copter1/mavros/global_position/global

/copter1/mavros/imu/data

...........

/copter2/mavros/global_position/global

/copter2/mavros/imu/data

...........
```

Maybe i must somehow disable autorun of roscore?
Or do something in bin directory.
(sorry for maybe uncorrect question: newbie)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268229/how-to-add-prefix-to-every-copter-in-erle-brain-using-mavros/) by [Sol](https://answers.ros.org/users/31466/sol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can remap topics using the [`remap` tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) in your launch files.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1